# html footer at bottom of window, content longer than window

Tags: jquery, css, html

i'm working on a website, it has a header, body, and footer.

I place the footer and header, written in different files, using jQuery.

I originally set the footer to a fixed position at the bottom. This worked for pages which had bodies shorter than the window. When I looked at another page with a longer body, the footer floated at that fixed point.

How can I keep the footer at the bottom, regardless of page/window length?

short page: http://jlzizmor.github.io/index.html 
long page: http://jlzizmor.github.io/resume.html

** EDIT: I implemented the CSS/HTML settings below and it works for what I described. However now, on the shorter pages, the footer doesn't end at the bottom of the page but a little lower? I've updated the links in the question if you could check it out.

Comment: maybe this will help you. http://jsfiddle.net/junkie/fAPQ6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

html:

```
 <div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="Header">header</div>
    <div class="Content">Content</div>
    <div class="FooterPush"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
```

css:

```
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}

html, body{height: 100%;}
.Header{background:blue;} 
.Wrapper{min-height: 100%;}
.Wrapper .FooterPush{height: 50px;}
.Footer{clear: both;position: relative;margin-top: -50px;height: 50px;background:red;}
```

demo ---->http://jsfiddle.net/junkie/fAPQ6/1/

Comment: I implemented the CSS/HTML settings above and it works for what I described. However now, on the shorter pages, the footer doesn't end at the bottom of the page but a little lower? I've updated the links in the question if you could check it out.

Comment: @jlzizmor , hi, because in this page your footer has 106px height. so you must set the class #wrapper #footer_push{height:106px;}  and #footer{height:106px; margin-top:106px;} , try it.

Comment: it works for the most part, however, the second line (the text) is pushed off the screen. How did you determine the number of pixels for the footer to get 106? This number could be off and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this style on your footer

```
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```